# $\sum a_n\to max$, where $a_n$ --- distance between $a$ and $\frac{m}{2^n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $a\in\mathbb R$, define a sequence $a_n$ --- distance from nearest number $\frac{m}{2^n}$, where $m\in\mathbb Z$.

Find maximal value of the sum $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n$.

Answer (score 0):

Bit incomplete solution.

Using inequality $\frac{1}{2^{n+1}} - a_n\geqslant a_{n+1}$, we have upper bound:
$$
\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n \leqslant \frac{2}{3}.
$$

But for number $a=\frac{2}{3}$ the sum is exactly $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n = \frac{2}{3}$.